# How to fix my MacBook's Menu bar that keeps flashing/blinking

Tags: macos, dock, error, menu-bar

I have a MacBook Air 2015 and the menu bar keeps flashing.
Also each time I click on one of the apps on the dock I get this error: gives an error like this:

[image]

"Terminal quick unexpectedly click reopens again... "

I can't access Terminal or another app.
The date on the menu bar states Sun Jan 5 but my computer was working perfectly a month ago.

After a while, this is another error message

[image]

"The last time you open finder it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows"

[image]
[image]

Specification:
Macbook Air 7.2
OS Version: [11.0.1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_v10.1)
The OS version seems odd to me as I purchased it brand new from Apple store back then
[image]

[Video of glitch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhrvoCpBXKqlAyThH5RJcXTNpdk6A957/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you try a Safe Boot (push shift key at boot)? Then you can do a Reset SMC : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 and a Reset NVRAM : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: Hi @Jean_JD! Thanks for the links!  I tried both instructions but that didn't fix it.

Comment: In Safe Mode Boot, have you the same problems?

Comment: It sounds like something in macOS is damaged (somehow...) I would reinstall your current version of macOS right over top of what is already there. The installer will replace the damaged parts of the OS and *should* leave everything else alone. I would back the system up, just in case...